# IIS timesout even for small running queries

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, webapi

IIS is timing out even for very small queries. When I run the stored procedure on sql server, it returns data fine less than .5 seconds. But it appears something blocking the call at IIS and it never reaches to sql server. I am using Linq to Sql to access the db. Its asp.net 4.7.2 Web Api application. Any suggestions and ideas welcome. Thanks

Comment: Check IIS log or failed request tracing log to see when IIS receive request and send response, and sql log to see when sql receive sql command. Then compare these time you will know where the timeout happen.

Comment: "When I run the stored procedure on sql server, it returns data fine": In many cases when you execute the same query from two different application then the time is different. This is a result of different connection string and setting of the session's parameters. It is very common for example that .Net app return result slow while SSMS return fast as a result of the ARITHABORT parameter ( which can be set to ON or OFF).

Comment: If this is happening with all queries, then it is a database connection issue. Check your connection string and check that your application can actually connect to the server/service hosting your DB.